# Google Datastore emulator - No matching index found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to run Google Cloud's Datastore emulator locally.

I ran into the issue where it was complaining that I didn't have a composite index.

```
(StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, no matching index found. recommended index is:<br/>- kind: taskgroups<br/>  properties:<br/>  - name: state<br/>  - name: available_tasks<br/>)>
```

I modified index.yaml file in `~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/index.yaml` to the following:

```
 indexes:
 - kind: taskgroups
   properties:
   - name: state
     direction: asc
   - name: available_tasks
     direction: asc
```

However, I still above error after restarting the datastore emulator. I am running it with `--no-store-on-disk` options.

`gcloud beta emulators datastore start --no-legacy --no-store-on-disk`

What should be done to make sure to apply changes made to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index.yaml should be in the application folder and not in the emulator folder